# JQuery-v1.3.2 Compatible Jstree

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jstree

I need to build tree like representation for my application. For that I am using latest version of JStree-tree builder util. This util package contains latest version of jQuery.

But my application uses some older version JQuery-v1.3.2. If I update jQuery of my application to latest version it is back pain to migrate the existing code. So can any one point me to the jquery-jstree.js which is compatible to JQuery-v1.3.2?

Comment: how are you using `noConflict()`?. You can run 2 versions of jQuery using it if done properly and assuming you aren't able to find compatible plugin version

Comment: @ charlietfl.. I have updated my Post.. So now I need JQuery-v1.3.2 Compatible jquery-jstree.js..

Comment: chances are you may not find one so you haven't answered the question I asked about `noConflict`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is strange you have issues upgrading site to current version of jQuery as most upgrades are backwards compatible. This is something the jQuery team has been very conscious of. One of the few exceptions may be useage of `attr` method

You can load 2 versions of jQuery and run both as isolated instances if you do it this way:

```
<script src="path/to/jQuery compatible with plugin"></script>
<script>
  /* must call this before loading other version*/
  $jQ_1.8= $.noConflict();
</script>
<script src="jquery-1.3"></script>

<script>
/* use "$" as you normally do for exisitng site code*/
  $(function(){
      /* code using 1.3*/
  })

/* for higher version jQuery use different *document.ready**/
$jQ_1.8(function( $){/* pass "$" as argument to allow using "$" in code if you want*/
  $(selector).pluginThatUsesDifferentVerion()

})
```